# Error in implementing client-side encryption in snowflake

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

using Amazon S3 encryption client i have encrypted my data locally using this code as reference(https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/dafa928e7b893ff63301c78a862e79bd168830c2/ruby/example_code/s3/s3_add_csaes_encrypt_item.rb) and put it to s3. I am able to retrieve it from s3 to local and decrypt the data. But when I use snowflake and decrypt it using Master Key...i am getting some encoded string.

string to encrypt - 'hello'
Master key generated using openssl - ����f�d/�U��oH�H�_�|`y-���I�♫
Master Key in Base-64 format - '9Yn7sWaQZC+YVYODb0ijSBubgF+zfGB5Le+3welJ2A4='
Data Key stored in metadata of s3(encrypted by Master Key and base-64 encoded) - uqkB9xGodxCD+Y/SA9Fq2XkhSmW+uiXFNbVg5fXTX/gVADS3vxTNfeZ/kosT+KN6jf7WL04TIzg9QhXZ
encoded string - Èàáµ~w$T}O—b‡˜]@ú/

after decrypting in snowflake - '0xC80xE00xE10xB50x02~w$T}O0x97b0x870x98]@0xFA/'
error thrown in snowflake - Invalid UTF8 detected in string

Followed all the steps according to documentation.
**any help is much appreciated**

Comment: Could you include the link to the documentation you followed on the Snowflake side?

Comment: This is the one i followed---https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-encryption.html#client-side-encryption

Comment: Can you query the data from the stage that contains the key information using a SELECT?  Without seeing how you've created your stage and knowing your key information, this is difficult to diagnose for you.